# Gravitational/electromagnetic effect of planets on solar activity?

Tags: astrophysics, planets, sun, solar-system

Does the gravitational and/or electromagnetic influence of planets have any effect or correspondence to solar activities (e.g. solar flares/CMEs) - and if so, does the planetary position (where they are in their orbit in regards to distance from the sun) have an effect? How do we know?

Comment: It is a curious coincidence(?) that the solar activity cycle is about the orbital period of Jupiter...

Comment: Wow, yes it appears to be very close. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a subject that gets plenty of crackpots excited. **But** there is some respectable, peer reviewed work out there if you can pick your way through the dross.

For example [Stefani et al. (2016)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11207-016-0968-0) have done some theoretical work, claiming that the 11.07 year cycle with which the tidal effects of Jupiter, the Earth and Venus line up, *might* excite a resonance in the $\alpha$ part of the $\alpha-\Omega$ dynamo. This resonance could lead to the solar magnetic cycle.

Another example is [Abreu et al. (2012)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012A%26A...548A..88A), who hypothesise a non-spherical tachocline (the seat of the solar dynamo) upon which a variable torque is applied by the planets. The Fourier transform of 9000-odd years of solar activity records shows a remarkable agreement with a Fourier transform of the planetary torque.

I cannot and do not vouch for any of thus work and they certainly [have their critics](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014A%26A...561A.132C).

One of the problems that any such hypotheses may have to address is that there does seems to be a complicated relationship between magnetic activity cycle period and rotation period in a substantial sample of solar-type stars (e.g. [Broomhall 2017](https://www.epj-conferences.org/articles/epjconf/pdf/2017/29/epjconf_azores2017_02009.pdf)). Since the rotation period changes with age it is not clear then how the cycle period could have anything to do with planets.